# Setting verbosity level from list of function arguments

Tags: bash, options

I am using a bash function to which I pass arguments.  I would like to capture if a particular option was defined by the user `-v NUM` or `--verbosity=NUM`.  If defined as described, I would like to set tho local variable `vb` to `NUM`.

Comment: That's boiling down to how to parse GNU-style long options in `bash`. If on Linux, you can have a look at the `getopt` command from `util-linux`. You'll find several Q&As discussing it here. If not on Linux, see my https://github.com/stephane-chazelas/misc-scripts/blob/master/getopts_long.sh (for sh but would work as well for bash).

Comment: Only thing I want to do is loop through `#@` and set `vb` that way.  No `getopts`, `getopt` or anything.

Comment: And what if the user passes `-xyv3` (same as `-x -y -v 3`) or `--output -v2` (same as `--output=-v2`, where `-v2` is the argument to the `--output` option) or `cmd -x -- foo bar -v baz` (where `-v` is not to be treated as an option), or `--verb=12` (abbreviation as supported in GNU option style parsing)? `getopt` / `getopts` are there to help you parse options properly.

Comment: Let's disregard fictitious possibilities that are irrelevant to my case.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start by saying that a blind scan of the arguments like that would fail to find all the valid ways the verbosity is to be specified if we assume the aim is to accept GNU-style long options.

What if the user passes `-xyv3` (same as `-x` `-y` `-v` `3`) or `--output` `-v2` (same as `--output=-v2`, where `-v2` is the argument to the `--output` option) or `cmd` `-x` `--` `foo` `bar` `-v` `baz` (where `-v` is not to be treated as an option), or `--verb=12` (abbreviation as supported in GNU option style parsing)? `getopt` / `getopts` are there to help you parse options properly.

But if you don't care about proper option parsing, and can rely on the  user always passing the `-v` / `--verbosity` option like that and not passing those strings as non-option arguments otherwise, you could do:

```
extract_verbosity() {
  unset -v REPLY
  while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
      (-v)
        [ "$#" -gt 1 ] || break
        shift; REPLY=$1
      ;;
         
      (--verbosity=*)
        REPLY=${1#*=}
    esac
    shift
  done
  [ -n "${REPLY+set}" ]
}
```

and then in your function:

```
my_function() {
  verbosity=0 # default
  extract_verbosity "$@" && verbosity=$REPLY
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why not use -v, -vv, -vvv as different (but similar) cases (unless you need an immense range of verbosities)? You could still have a long-form `--verbosity=NUM`

Comment: Once you perform the argument shift, can one reset `$@` back to its original values ?

Comment: After calling getopt, should I first check for errors (using `#?`) or check the parameters nevertheless ? And only then issue the error messages?  My current problem is that the error message is dependent on the verbosity level.

Comment: @Isabel, `extract_verbosity` processes it's own list of arguments (which is the same as `my_function`'s as `my_function` called it  with `"$@"`). It leaves its caller's list of arguments untouched.

Comment: @isabel, yes, you'd typically do `code="set -- $(getopt...)" || { usage; exit 1; }; eval "$code"`